# How to convert matrix elements from 0|1 to 1|0 in R?

Tags: r, matrix, graph, element

I have a graph that converted to matrix.

```
g = sample_k_regular(10,3)
m =get.adjacency(g)
```

I want to select randomly some elements and convert to 0|1.(if it is 0 to become 1 and if it is 1 to become 0).

How to do this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `sample` of `n` elements (10 in example) and change it

```
m1=as.matrix(m)
m1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1     1
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     1
 [4,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     1
 [7,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1     0
 [9,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
[10,]    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
set.seed(1)
ss=sample(length(m1),size = 10)
m1[ss]=1-m1[ss]
m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    1     1
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     1
 [4,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    1     1
 [7,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0     1
 [8,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1     0
 [9,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     0
[10,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
```

For exclude diagonal as @ZheyuanLi told

you can calculate diad position and exlude it from data for sample :

```
m1=as.matrix(m)
m1
set.seed(1)
m_l=1:length(m1)
m_l=m_l[-which(diag(1,nrow = nrow(m1))==1)]
ss=sample(m_l,size = 10)
m1[ss]=1-m1[ss]
m1
```

For big matrix beter use `seq.int` than `diag`

```
n=1000

Unit: microseconds
                                            expr      min       lq        mean     median        uq        max neval
           {     which(diag(1, nrow = n) == 1) } 8976.718 9422.967 14397.44991 10489.0520 16001.550 190959.200   100
          {     seq(1, by = n + 1, length = n) }   12.941   17.404    37.90449    31.9075    56.004     83.448   100
      {     seq.int(1, by = n + 1, length = n) }    5.355    6.248     8.90736     7.1405    12.272     16.512   100
 {     1 + {         (1:n) - 1     } * (1 + n) }    5.355    6.248     9.77758     8.9255    11.826     25.437   100
```